# .readline is not returning even when there's a new line

Tags: python, process

I have two Python scripts where script A should constantly read a line from script B:

Script A (controller):

```
import sys, subprocess

r = subprocess.Popen(["python", "script_b.py"], 
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

while True:
    data = r.stdout.readline().strip()
    if not data:
        break

    print("Data: \"{}\"".format(data))
```

Script B (receiver):

```
import sys

for i in xrange(3):
    sys.stdout.write("%d\n" % i)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Strangely, script B writes a newline as well as flushing after every writes, but script A never prints out anything. If I switch script A to use `sys.stdin` instead, it would work in the terminal. Why is that?

Comment: Try it without `shell=True`, I seem to recall this can cause problems when reading the stdout of the subprocess

Comment: That indeed fixed the problem! But why is that the case?

Comment: call b from a (mean external app) which app handle output/input?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I couldn't tell you exactly, I suppose because `shell=True` means that the processes will spawn an intermediate shell process, i.e. on Linux, it actually uses `/bin/sh`, and then the output of the command to the shell isn't actually the stdout of the *shell process*, but I'm no Unix expert.

Comment: Also, don't use a `while` loop, just `for line in r.stdout: print(line)`

Comment: Also, scripy_b could just be `for i in range(3): print('%d'%i)`